# Catch an entire function with grep

Tags: bash, unix, grep

In want to replace a function in a file by another. I have this :

File1.cpp:

```
void Component::initialize()
{
    my_component = new ComponentClass();
}
```

and File2.cpp:

```
void Component::initialize()
{
    if (doInit)
    {
        my_component = new ComponentClass();
    }
    else
    {
        my_component.ptr = null;
    }
}
```

I've try to write a script but my grep does not provide a result :

```
Old=$(grep -Eo "void Component::initialize(\n|.)*(^})*?" file1.cpp)
echo "Old=$Old" # empty variable

# My purpose is to do this :
New=$(grep -Eo "void Component::initialize(\n|.)*(^})*?" file2.cpp)
sed -i "s/$Old/$New/g" file1.cpp
```

Comment: needs ")" twice in bash sample and decide File* or file*? If i add 2  ")" end of line and rename files File* as file* it gives the expected output. Please test your sample before posting in here.

Comment: A regex is not really suitable for this; to parse code properly, you need a parser.

Comment: Use `awk` to imolement more clever things.

Comment: I took a look at awk but I never used it and I've no idea how to deal with my problem

Comment: @A.Pissicat Perhaps use a language that allows multi-line search instead. Ruby or Perl.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some background information. Do you have to replace the function in more than one file? Do `File1.cpp` and `File2.cpp` contain more code? If yes, then add some example code. (Otherwise `cp File2.cpp File1.cpp`) Are the functions always formatted and indented like in your example, i.e. no other curly braces in the first column, function name and arguments in a single line, opening brace of the function block in a new line below the function name?

Comment: You could always take at look at [**this posting**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32908/how-to-insert-the-content-of-a-file-into-another-file-before-a-pattern-marker) offering sed-based approaches to a similar problem.  The issue is correctly identifying the match/replace patterns.

Comment: You might want to review this [**section**](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiline-techniques.html) on multi-line handling.  There might be a solution there, but I am not a sed master.

Comment: Just another thought: Why not creating a subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^void Component::initialize\(\)$/ {
    temp = $0

    while (!/^}/ && getline > 0)
        temp = temp ORS $0

    if (NR == FNR) {
        new = temp
        nextfile
    }

    $0 = new
}

NR != FNR
```

Usage:

```
awk -f script.awk file{2,1}.cpp
```

Comment: very nice.  note well that files must be linted for this to work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a **grep**-centric **bash** **script** solution (since **these** are what the OP mentioned explicitly):

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat replaceFunc.sh 
#!/bin/bash

# presumes code has been lint'd into consistent format 

oldFile=$1
newFile=$2

# find line # (oldFuncLineNum) of "void Component::initialize()" line
oldFuncLineNum=`cat $oldFile | grep -n '^void Component::initialize()$' | cut -c 1`

# find line # (oldSquiglyLineNum) of first "}" line after oldFuncLineNum
oldSquiglyLineNum=1
while [ $oldSquiglyLineNum -lt $oldFuncLineNum ]
do
  found=0
  while [ $found -eq 0 ]
  do
    oldSquiglyLineNum=`expr $oldSquiglyLineNum + 1`
    head -n $oldSquiglyLineNum $oldFile | tail -n 1 | grep '^}$' > /dev/null
    found=`test ! -f $? && echo "1" || echo "0"`
  done
done

oldTotSize=`sed -n '$=' $oldFile`
oldTailSize=`expr $oldTotSize - $oldSquiglyLineNum`

#echo "got: oldFuncLineNum = $oldFuncLineNum"
#echo "got: oldSquiglyLineNum = $oldSquiglyLineNum"
#echo "got oldTotSize = $oldTotSize"
#echo "oldTailSize = $oldTailSize"


# find line # (newFuncLineNum) of "void Component::initialize()" line
newFuncLineNum=`cat $newFile | grep -n '^void Component::initialize()$' | cut -c 1`

# find line # (newSquiglyLineNum) of first "}" line after newFuncLineNum
newSquiglyLineNum=1
while [ $newSquiglyLineNum -lt $newFuncLineNum ]
do
  found=0
  while [ $found -eq 0 ]
  do
    newSquiglyLineNum=`expr $newSquiglyLineNum + 1`
    head -n $newSquiglyLineNum $newFile | tail -n 1 | grep '^}$' > /dev/null
    found=`test ! -f $? && echo "1" || echo "0"`
  done
done

newDelta=`expr $newSquiglyLineNum - $newFuncLineNum`

#echo "got: newFuncLineNum = $newFuncLineNum"
#echo "got: newSquiglyLineNum = $newSquiglyLineNum"
#echo "got: newDelta = $newDelta"


# Display oldFile up to the function:
cat $oldFile | head -n $oldFuncLineNum

# ... followed by the new function:
cat $newFile | head -n $newSquiglyLineNum | tail -n $newDelta

# ... followed by the remaining portion of the oldFile:
cat $oldFile | tail -n $oldTailSize

exit 0
Mac_3.2.57$
Mac_3.2.57$
Mac_3.2.57$
Mac_3.2.57$cat File1.cpp 
blah blah
blah
void Component::initialize()
{
    my_component = new ComponentClass();
}
blab blab blab
...
Mac_3.2.57$
Mac_3.2.57$
Mac_3.2.57$
Mac_3.2.57$cat File2.cpp 
yaddy yadda
yaddy yadda
void Component::initialize()
{
    if (doInit)
    {
        my_component = new ComponentClass();
    }
    else
    {
        my_component.ptr = null;
    }
}
blah
blah
blab blab blab
...
Mac_3.2.57$
Mac_3.2.57$
Mac_3.2.57$
Mac_3.2.57$./replaceFunc.sh File1.cpp File2.cpp
blah blah
blah
void Component::initialize()
{
    if (doInit)
    {
        my_component = new ComponentClass();
    }
    else
    {
        my_component.ptr = null;
    }
}
blab blab blab
...
Mac_3.2.57$
```

Comment: My solution, now deleted, focused on the problem (locate/replace), not on the method (grep vs sed).  That proposed solution offered what I considered a generic/simplistic/elegant approach (canned routine + mapping specification file).

Answer (score 0):

Circling back with a working solution to my original non-functional answer (now deleted).

I managed to work thru the issue with the original defective **[sed](/questions/tagged/sed)** script posted on linuxtopia, and was able to get the **generic solution** I was looking for.  That is given as an answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75305074/trying-to-get-generic-sed-multi-line-pattern-match-and-substitution-script-to-wo).

Comment: @Andrew, just want to point out that the OP selected a solution which did not involve grep, but instead used awk.  As I originally commented, the specific solution that was selected was one I had thought of before it was posted, but wanted to present a more generic solution.  I was happy that I was able to finally resolve the issue with the modification of a previously published (but non-functional) solution.