# Trying to get generic sed multi-line pattern match and substitution script to work

Tags: bash, sed, code-transformation

There is a generic approach to solving the problem presented [by this poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75220171/catch-an-entire-function-with-grep/75252250#75252250) which is presented on [linuxtopia](/questions/tagged/linuxtopia) [**here**](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_013.html), in **section 4.23.3** .  *It appears to offer a method for handling any complex content pattern for matching target, then replacing that with, again, any other complex content pattern.*  The technique is referred to as the "**sliding-window**" technique.

I believe the below script faithfully recreates the scenario described and attempts to incorporate the sed script to demonstrate that approach as workable.

```
#!/bin/bash

DBG=1

###
### Code segment to be replaced
###
file1="File1.cpp"
rm -f "${file1}"
cat >"${file1}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
void Component::initialize()
{
    my_component = new ComponentClass();
}
EnDoFiNpUt

test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo "fence 1"

###
### Code segment to be used as replacement
###
file2="File2.cpp"
rm -f "${file2}"
cat >"${file2}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
void Component::initialize()
{
    if (doInit)
    {
        my_component = new ComponentClass();
    }
    else
    {
        my_component.ptr = null;
    }
}
EnDoFiNpUt

test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo "fence 2"

###
### Create demo input file
###
testfile="Test_INPUT.cpp"
rm -f "${testfile}"
{
    echo "
other code1()
{
    doing other things
    doing more things
    doing extra things
} 
"
    cat "${file1}"

echo "
other code2()
{
    creating other things
    creating more things
    creating extra things
} 
"
} >>"${testfile}"

test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo "fence 3"

###
### Create editing specification file
###
{
    cat "${file1}"
    echo "###REPLACE_BY###"
    cat "${file2}"
} >findrep.txt

test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo "fence 4"


###
### sed script to create editing instructions to apply aove editing specification file
###
cat >"blockrep.sed" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
#SOURCE:    https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_013.html
#
# filename: blockrep.sed
#   author: Paolo Bonzini
# Requires:
#    (1) blocks to find and replace, e.g., findrep.txt
#    (2) an input file to be changed, input.file
#
# blockrep.sed creates a second sed script, custom.sed,
# to find the lines above the row of 4 hyphens, globally
# replacing them with the lower block of text. GNU sed
# is recommended but not required for this script.
#
# Loop on the first part, accumulating the `from' text
# into the hold space.
:a
/^###REPLACE_BY###$/! {
   # Escape slashes, backslashes, the final newline and
   # regular expression metacharacters.
   s,[/\[.*],\\&,g
   s/$/\\/
   H
   #
   # Append N cmds needed to maintain the sliding window.
   x
   1 s,^.,s/,
   1! s/^/N\
/
   x
   n
   ba
}
#
# Change the final backslash to a slash to separate the
# two sides of the s command.
x
s,\\$,/,
x
#
# Until EOF, gather the substitution into hold space.
:b
n
s,[/\],\\&,g
$! s/$/\\/
H
$! bb
#
# Start the RHS of the s command without a leading
# newline, add the P/D pair for the sliding window, and
# print the script.
g
s,/\n,/,
s,$,/\
P\
D,p
#---end of script---
EnDoFiNpUt

test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo "fence 5"


sed --debug -nf blockrep.sed findrep.txt >custom.sed
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo "fence 6"

if [ -s custom.sed ]
then
    more custom.sed
    echo -e "\t Hit return to continue ..." >&2
    read k <&2
else
    echo -e "\t Failed to create 'custom.sed'.  Unable to proceed!\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi

testout="Test_OUTPUT.cpp"

sed -f custom.sed "${testfile}" >"${testout}"
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo "fence 7"

if [ -s "${testout}" ]
then
    more "${testout}"
else
    echo -e "\t Failed to create '${testout}'.\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Unfortunately, what they presented doesn't seem to work.  I wish there was something like bash's "set -x" for command expansion/reporting of sed execution to stderr, but I haven't found anything like that.

The execution log for the above is as follows:

```
fence 1
fence 2
fence 3
fence 4
fence 5
sed: file blockrep.sed line 19: unterminated `s' command
fence 6
     Failed to create 'custom.sed'.  Unable to proceed!
```

Maybe an expert out there can resolve the logic error in the imported **blockrep.sed** script ... because I can't get my head wrapped around it to fix it, even with all the comments provided.

I openly attest to the fact that I am very simplistic/limited in both my knowledge, and my usage, of sed.  I couldn't begin to understand how that "**blockrep.sed**" script is trying to do what it claims, only that it states all content of **findrep.txt**, *before the defined separator string "**###REPLACE_BY###**"*, is to be replaced by all below that same separator.

In my view, the approach identified by the linuxtopia guide **would have broad application and be beneficial for many**, including the OP and myself.

Comment: so you're married to `sed` to solve this problem? It would be much easier to solve with `awk` or `perl` or many others. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter, I rarely use sed for complex problems; usually only for short string strip/mapping.  AWK is my preferred tool, as evidenced by my responses to other postings.  However, **I love the simplicity of the approach proposed by the linuxtopia solution**, and would like to get my hands on a working version of that.

Comment: I tried implementing the code from linixopedia but got `sed: file blockrep.sed line 18: unterminated `s' command`. When I (thought) I fixed that, the script did not perform as expected. Did it work for you? Don't have much time to spend on this. Good luck in your endeavors!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/492893

Comment: @shelter, as in my OP, I got the **same error message* for sed. :-(

Comment: @shellter, Thank you for looking at this.  The --debug option did not work for me on sed (version: sed (GNU sed) 4.7 ; Ubuntu MATE 20.04 / Linux 5.4.0-135-generic #152-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 23 20:19:22 UTC 2022).  I got the same output with or without (I removed the -n option and that made no difference).  Is there a way/need to specify the debug option on each individual line in the sed script?

Comment: There are `sed` specific news  groups. `alt.comp.sed`? or something like that. Or look for a developers forum specific to the gnu sed. I assume you  looked at `man sed` and `info sed` (this might have more info). And I assume that if your `sed` accepted `--debug` without an error message, then you have a version. Try installing other versions? I would expect Ubunutu sed =  gsed, but I guess you have to confirm that in your environment. Good luck.

Comment: *" in my OP, I got the *same error message for sed."". Oh right. After  I had posted that comment, I had a thought that *someone* had written "It didn't work for me either". Sorry to have added some noise to your discovery. Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resorted to discretizing portions of the **blockrep.sed** script to see if I could identify a source of breakdown.  While that made no logical difference on the surface, that did create a functional and well-formed structure ... which **did** create a usable **custom.sed**, but only after I removed the **--debug** option for the execution of *blockrep.sed*.  *That is required because the degug info is not sent to the stderr, but is inline with the stdout !!!*  I don't know enought to classify that as a bug.

**NOTE:** I've also added **command-line options** to specify names of files for input, output, old_pattern, new_pattern, divider, among others.

**The now modified and working version** of the script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

reportFiles ()
{
    ls -l "${fileSrchPat}" "${fileReplPat}" "findrep.txt" 2>&1
    ls -l "blockrep.sed" "custom.sed" "custom.err" 2>&1
    ls -l "${fileBefore}" 2>&1
    ls -l "${fileOutput}" 2>&1
}


DBG=0
DBGs=0
dumA=1 ;
dumB=1 ;
fileSrchPat=""
fileReplPat=""
divider="----REPLACE_BY----"
doReview=0
fileBefore=""
fileOutput=""

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        --debug )
            DBG=1 ;
            shift ;;
        --debug_sed )
            DBGs=1 ;
            shift ;;
        --verbose )
            set -x
            shift ;;
        --old_pattern )
            dumA=0 ;
            fileSrchPat="$2" ;
            if [ ! -s "${fileSrchPat}" ]
            then
                echo -e "\n File '${fileSrchPat}' not found.\n Bye!\n"
                exit 1
            fi ;
            shift ; shift ;;
        --new_pattern )
            dumA=0 ;
            fileReplPat="$2" ;
            if [ ! -s "${fileReplPat}" ]
            then
                echo -e "\n File '${fileReplPat}' not found.\n Bye!\n"
                exit 1
            fi ;
            shift ; shift ;; 
        --pattern_sep )
            divider="$2" ;
            shift ; shift ;;
        --input )
            dumB=0 ;
            fileBefore="$2" ;
            if [ ! -s "${fileBefore}" ]
            then
                echo -e "\n File '${fileBefore}' not found.\n Bye!\n"
                exit 1
            fi ;
            shift ; shift ;;
        --output )
            fileOutput="$2" ;
            if [ ! -s "${fileOutput}" ]
            then
                echo -e "\n File '${fileOutput}' already exists.  Overwrite ? [y|N] => \c"
                read goAhead
                if [ -z "${goAhead}" ] ; then  goAhead="N" ; fi
                case ${goAhead} in
                    y* | Y* ) rm -vf "${fileOutput}" ;;
                    * ) echo -e "\n\t Process abandonned.\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ;;
                esac
                exit 1
            fi ;
            shift ; shift ;;
        --review ) doReview=1 ; shift ;;
        * ) echo "\n invalid option used on command line.  Only valid options: [ --old_pattern {textfile1} | --new_pattern {textfile2} ] \n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

###
### Code segment to be replaced
###
if [ -z "${fileSrchPat}" ]
then
    fileSrchPat="File1.cpp"
    rm -f "${fileSrchPat}"
    cat >"${fileSrchPat}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
void Component::initialize()
{
    my_component = new ComponentClass();
}
EnDoFiNpUt

fi
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\n\t ======== fence 1"


###
### Code segment to be used as replacement
###
if [ -z "${fileReplPat}" ]
then
    fileReplPat="File2.cpp"
    rm -f "${fileReplPat}"
    cat >"${fileReplPat}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
void Component::initialize()
{
    if (doInit)
    {
        my_component = new ComponentClass();
    }
    else
    {
        my_component.ptr = null;
    }
}
EnDoFiNpUt

fi
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\n\t ======== fence 2"


if [ -z "${fileBefore}" ]
then
###
### Create demo input file
###
    fileBefore="Test_INPUT.cpp"
    rm -f "${fileBefore}"
    {
    echo "
other code1()
{
    doing other things
    doing more things
    doing extra things
} 
"
    cat "${fileSrchPat}"

    echo "
other code2()
{
    creating other things
    creating more things
    creating extra things
} 
"
    } >>"${fileBefore}"

fi
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\n\t ======== fence 3"

###
### Create editing specification file
###
{
    cat "${fileSrchPat}"
    echo "${divider}"
    cat "${fileReplPat}"
} >findrep.txt

test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\n\t ======== fence 4"


###
### sed script to create editing instructions to apply above editing specification file
###
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && rm -fv "blockrep.sed" || rm -f "blockrep.sed"

cat >"blockrep.sed" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
#SOURCE:    https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_013.html
#
# filename: blockrep.sed
#   author: Paolo Bonzini
# 
# Modified by: Eric Marceau, Feb 2023
#
# Requires:
#    (1) blocks to find and replace, e.g., findrep.txt
#    (2) an input file to be changed, input.file
#
# blockrep.sed creates a second sed script, custom.sed,
# to find the lines above the row of 4 hyphens, globally
# replacing them with the lower block of text. GNU sed
# is recommended but not required for this script.
#
# Loop on the first part, accumulating the `from' text
# into the hold space.
#
##############################################################################
### Reworked Discretized version of coding
##############################################################################
#
##############################################################################
### Begin of capture - SEARCH pattern
##############################################################################
:markerA
EnDoFiNpUt

#echo "/^----REPLACE_BY----\$/! {" >> "blockrep.sed"
echo "/^${divider}\$/! {" >> "blockrep.sed"

cat >>"blockrep.sed" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
#
# Escape slashes
    s,[/],\\&,g
#
# Escape backslashes
    s,[\],\\&,g
#
# Escape regular expression metacharacters
    s,[[],\\&,g
    s,[.],\\&,g
    s,[*],\\&,g
#
# Escape the final newline
#  add backslash to end of line (to avoid having sed 
#  think of as end of command input)
    s,$,\\,
#
# APPEND  -  PATTERN space to HOLD space
    H
#
# Sequence to APPEND "N" cmds needed to maintain the sliding window.
# \\ swap contents - HOLD and PATTERN space
    x
#
# If first line, begin constructing sed command for pattern match and replace
    1 s,^.,s/,
#
# If not first line, add line with "N" 
#  i.e. give instruction to "APPEND the next line of input into the pattern space"
    1! s,^,N\
,
# // swap contents again - HOLD and PATTERN space
    x
#
# COPY  -  next line of input into PATTERN space
    n
#
# branch/jump to label markerA
    b markerA
}
#
##############################################################################
### End of capture - SEARCH pattern
##############################################################################
#
#
##############################################################################
### Begin of capture - REPLACEMENT pattern
##############################################################################
#
# \\ swap contents - HOLD and PATTERN space
    x
#
# Change the final backslash to a slash to separate the
# two sides of the s command.
    s,\\$,/,
#
# // swap contents again - HOLD and PATTERN space
    x
#
# Until EOF, gather the REPLACEMENT TEXT into the hold space.
:markerB
    n
#
# Escape slashes
    s,[/],\\&,g
#
# Escape backslashes
    s,[\],\\&,g
#
# If not last line, add backslash to escape all instances of "$".
    $! s,$,\\,
#
# APPEND  -  PATTERN space to HOLD space
    H
#
# If not last line, branch/jump to markerB
    $! b markerB
#
##############################################################################
### End of capture - SEARCH pattern
##############################################################################
#
#
# Start the Right-Hand Side (RHS) of the "s" command without a leading newline,
# add the P/D pair for the sliding window, and
# print the script.
#
# COPY  -  HOLD space to PATTERN space
    g
    s,/\n,/,
#
# (P) Print up to the first embedded newline of the current pattern space.
#  then
# (D) If  pattern  space  contains no newline, start a normal new cycle as if 
#   the d command was issued.  Otherwise, delete text in the pattern space 
#   up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space,
#   without reading a new line of input.
#  then
# (p) Print the current pattern space.
    s,$,/\
    P\
    D,p
#---end of script---
EnDoFiNpUt

test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\n\t ======== fence 5"

test ${DBG} -eq 1 && rm -fv custom.sed custom.err || rm -f custom.sed custom.err

if [ ${DBGs} -eq 1 ]
then
    echo -e "\n\t NOTE:  debug mode active for 'sed' command ..."
    sed --debug -f blockrep.sed findrep.txt >custom.sed 2>custom.err
else
    sed -nf blockrep.sed findrep.txt >custom.sed 2>custom.err
fi
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\n\t ======== fence 6"


if [ -s custom.err ]
then
    if [ ${doReview} -eq 1 ]
    then
        cat custom.err
    fi
fi
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\n\t ======== fence 7"


if [ -s custom.sed ]
then
    if [ ${doReview} -eq 1 ]
    then
        more custom.sed
        echo -e "\n\t Hit return to continue ..." >&2
        read k <&2
    fi
    if [ ${DBGs} -eq 1 ]
    then
        more custom.sed
        echo -e "\n =============  End of Review - 'custom.sed' containing execution debug reporting  =============" >&2
        echo -e "\n\t 'custom.sed' is not in usable form due to '--debug' messaging." >&2
        echo -e   "\t Abandoning before attempting final transformation.\n Bye!\n" >&2
        exit 2
    fi
else
    echo -e "\t Failed to create 'custom.sed'.  Unable to proceed!\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\n\t ======== fence 8"


if [ -z "${fileOutput}" ]
then
    fileOutput="Test_OUTPUT.cpp"
fi
rm -f "${fileOutput}"
sed -f custom.sed "${fileBefore}" >"${fileOutput}"
test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\n\t ======== fence 9"


if [ -s "${fileOutput}" ]
then
    test ${DBG} -eq 1 && echo -e "\n\t ======== fence 10"
    if [ ${doReview} -eq 1 ]
    then
        more "${fileOutput}"
    fi
    if [ ${DBG} -eq 1 ]
    then
        reportFiles
        if [ ${dumA} -eq 1 ]
        then
            rm -fv "${fileSrchPat}" "${fileReplPat}" 2>&1
        fi
        if [ ${dumB} -eq 1 ]
        then
            rm -fv "${fileBefore}" 2>&1
        fi
        rm -fv "findrep.txt" "custom.sed" "custom.err" "blockrep.sed" 2>&1
    else
        if [ ${dumA} -eq 1 ]
        then
            rm -f "${fileSrchPat}" "${fileReplPat}" 2>&1
        fi
        if [ ${dumB} -eq 1 ]
        then
            rm -f "${fileBefore}" 2>&1
        fi
        rm -f "findrep.txt" "custom.sed" "custom.err" "blockrep.sed" 2>&1
    fi | awk '{ printf("\t %s\n", $0 ) ; }' >&2
else
    echo -e "\t Failed to create '${fileOutput}'.\n" >&2
    reportFiles | awk '{ printf("\t %s\n", $0 ) ; }' >&2
    exit 1
fi


exit
```

**Using the following command to execute** (using default built-in demo case)

```
./script.sh --debug --review
```

**The resulting session output is**

```
     ======== fence 1
     ======== fence 2
     ======== fence 3
     ======== fence 4
     ======== fence 5
     ======== fence 6
     ======== fence 7
N
N
N
s/void Component::initialize()\
{\
    my_component = new ComponentClass();\
}/void Component::initialize()\
{\
    if (doInit)\
    {\
        my_component = new ComponentClass();\
    }\
    else\
    {\
        my_component.ptr = null;\
    }\
}/
    P
    D

     Hit return to continue ...

     ======== fence 8
     ======== fence 9
     ======== fence 10

other code1()
{
    doing other things
    doing more things
    doing extra things
} 

void Component::initialize()
{
    if (doInit)
    {
        my_component = new ComponentClass();
    }
    else
    {
        my_component.ptr = null;
    }
}

other code2()
{
    creating other things
    creating more things
    creating extra things
} 

 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered  71 Feb  4 16:05 File1.cpp
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered 130 Feb  4 16:05 File2.cpp
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered 220 Feb  4 16:05 findrep.txt
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered 3604 Feb  4 16:05 blockrep.sed
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered    0 Feb  4 16:05 custom.err
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered  229 Feb  4 16:05 custom.sed
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered 240 Feb  4 16:05 Test_INPUT.cpp
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 ericthered ericthered 299 Feb  4 16:06 Test_OUTPUT.cpp
 removed 'File1.cpp'
 removed 'File2.cpp'
 removed 'Test_INPUT.cpp'
 removed 'findrep.txt'
 removed 'custom.sed'
 removed 'custom.err'
 removed 'blockrep.sed'
```

Which is as was initially intended.  Success!

Comment: Good show!!!!!!

Comment: As long as all source code files are standardized, and elements were copy+pasted, the above solution will cover everything.   ...   Now, all I need to do is add logic to strip leading whitespaces, trailing whitespaces, and map multiple-whitespaces to a single-space, for both the match pattern, and the edited file "evaluation buffer", to allow for random format of manually entered copies, to ensure no cases are overlooked.  That will be a biggie!  Not sure that stripping/mapping can happen without affecting the format of the final output. :-(

Comment: Its good to have a challenging project to help improve your understandings. Good luck!

Comment: @shellter, do you know what "RHS" stands for ?  I've search online and looked at many of the sed books and none make mention of what that acronym means.  Does it mean "Replace/Hold Space" or "Run/Hold Space" ?  Is that RHS acronym documented anywhere that is officially related to the sed project ?

Comment: Yes, that is an obscure one. And good guess, but almost always `RightHandSide` vs `LeftHandSide (LHS)`, as in `if (LHS < RHS); ....` . Probably also applies to `s/LHS/RHS/`. (I think!) . ... Does that make sense for your context? Good luck.

Comment: Very much appreciated!